Getting error UserController does not exist on form
I had a working user login/register form that worked. Receently I intallled the Image Intervention to resize images. Not sure if the installion and the composer updates made a change to my settings. Now I get this error. I am using Laravel 10.
target class [App\Http\Controllers\UserController] does not exist.

Checked the routes settings.
Ran composer -dump autoload and got
Class App\Models\User\AppServiceProvider located in ...... app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

autoloading issue.install composer again composer install.

Thanks. Somehow I deleted the UserController under Controllers.

And finally you found it.
